# Merge test code coverage in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, code-coverage, jacoco, test-coverage

We are running unit tests and acceptance tests in Teamcity, both for Java for the same project. Both generate a test coverage report using JaCoCo.

Is there a way to merge the test coverage reports, so that we can see what code is not covered by either suite?

Answer (score 0):

The coverage report is already published as a hidden artifact after each build. It would need to be imported to the acceptance tests step and referenced by maven, as of this:
http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/merge-mojo.html